# im trying to make textured glass but it doesn't work the way i want, can any help?

Tags: glass

so i have been trying to make a glass block in blender with a Minecraft image texture node. and every time i tried it works but it doesn't. the texture shows but the center is black
[image: i know the transparency is not activated.]
[image: with transparency]

Answer (score 1):

In the material properties tab (next to main viewport), with the material selected,  scroll down until you see *Blend Mode* and *Shadow Mode* (under *Settings*). Set Blend Mode to *Alpha-clip*, *Alpha-hashed*, or *Alpha-blend* (play and see what looks best).

The other controls the shadows created by the transparency. Also, play around to see what looks best, or just leave it off if you don't need it to have a shadow.

Also, make sure to connect the alpha from your image texture to the BSDF node, or adjust the value as needed ($0$ is pure transparent).